# How to deploy home-grown applications with rpm?

Tags: unix, deployment, installation, uninstallation, rpm

here is my scenario

- our team develops on **AIX**
- dozens of applications, mostly Perl, shell scripts, batch java, C
- i would like to simplify deployment/rollback procedures - currently using plain old tarballs with backups
- I looked into installp vs. rpm for packaging (see [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865049/aix-deployment-installp-or-rpm)) and decided to go with **rpm** - better docs, plus IBM included it while having their own packaging tool, so this is a valid reason for me
- i would want to use a separate rpm db, not the main one - for I don't have **root** access and I also feel it would be beneficial to separate OS apps from our stuff.

---

the **workflow** would look like:

- each app has a corresponding rpm.spec - checked-in into source control
- build an rpm in a home dir
- install/upgrade while using our own **packages.rpm**

*NOTE : I will use this question as notes to myself as I proceed*

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building rpm's in my home :

**1**.

I need a **.rpmmacros** file in my user's root which overrides some system-wide rpm settings

```
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_name {yourname}
%_gpg_path ~/.gnupg
%distribution AIX 5.3
%vendor {Northwind? :)}
%make   make
```

**2**.

this will create directory structure needed for rpm builds, it will also update **.rpmmacros**

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "x$1" = "x-d" ] && {
DEBUG="y"
export DEBUG
shift 1
}

IAM=`id -un`
PASSWDDIR=`grep ^$IAM: /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $6}'`
HOMEDIR=${HOME:=$PASSWDDIR}

[ ! -d $HOMEDIR ] && {
echo "ERROR: Home directory for user $IAM not found in /etc/passwd."
exit 1
}

RHDIR="$HOMEDIR/rpmbuild"
RPMMACROS="$HOMEDIR/.rpmmacros"
touch $RPMMACROS

TOPDIR="%_topdir"
ISTOP=`grep -c ^$TOPDIR $RPMMACROS`
[ $ISTOP -lt 1 ] && {
echo "%_topdir      $HOMEDIR/rpmbuild" >> $RPMMACROS
}

TMPPATH="%_tmppath"
ISTMP=`grep -c ^$TMPPATH $RPMMACROS`
[ $ISTMP -lt 1 ] && {
echo "%_tmppath $HOMEDIR/rpmbuild/tmp" >> $RPMMACROS
}

[ "x$DEBUG" != "x" ] && {
echo "$IAM       $HOMEDIR    $RPMMACROS"
echo "$RHDIR     $TOPDIR     $ISTOP"
}

[ ! -d $RHDIR ] && mkdir -p $RHDIR

cd $RHDIR 
for i in RPMS SOURCES SPECS SRPMS BUILD tmp ; do 
[ ! -d ./$i ] && mkdir ./$i 
done

exit 0
```

you could check if rpm picked up your changes with :

```
rpm --showrc | grep topdir
```

**3.**

specify a non-default location of the RPM database, such as the following:

```
rpm --dbpath /location/of/your/rpm/database --initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually check in my spec files to the same place that my code is.

I run a build server (I use Hudson) to kick off a build every night (could be continuous but I chose nightly).  The build server checks out the code, builds it, and runs rpmbuild.  Hudson sets up a workspace folder that can be deleted after each build so if you set %_topdir to point to that area then you can guarantee there won't be build artifacts left over from a previous build.  At the end of the build I check my rpms into version control with a comment containing the build number.

Rolling back is a matter of pulling out the last good rpm from version control, erasing the current rpm, and installing the old rpm.

Sounds like you already have a good handle on using your own package db.